# Java.lang.NullPointerexception at Cafévoetbalploeg.getDoelpuntensaldo(...)

Tags: java

I get the error in the title with this. This is when I compile it and when I want to use the method.

```
    import java.util.*;
/**
 * De algemene informatie van de caféploeg komt in deze klasse te staan.
 * 
 * @author Thomas Claes
 * @version 1.00
 */
public class Cafévoetbalploeg
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String naam;
    private int stichtingsjaar;
    private String plaats;
    private int aantalGewonnenWedstrijden;
    private int doelpuntensaldo;
    private Wedstrijd wedstrijd;
    private ArrayList<Wedstrijd> wedstrijden;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Cafévoetbalploeg
     */
    public Cafévoetbalploeg() {
        stichtingsjaar = 0;
        doelpuntensaldo = 0;
        aantalGewonnenWedstrijden = 0;
        wedstrijden = new ArrayList<Wedstrijd>();
    }





    /**
     *De naam van de ploeg
     *
     *@param ploegnaam geef de naam van de ploeg in
     */
    public void naam(String ploegnaam) {
        naam = ploegnaam;


    }
    /**
     * Voeg een nieuwe wedstrijd toe aan de lijst met wedstrijden
     * 
     * @param wedstrijd wedstrijd is een bepaalde wedstrijd die je toevoegd aan de lijst met wedstrijden.
     */
     public void nieuweWedstrijd(Wedstrijd wedstrijd) {

        wedstrijden.add(wedstrijd);


    }

    /**
     *Het stichtingsjaar
     *
     *@param jaar geef het stichtingsjaar in
     */
    public void stichtingsjaar(int jaar) {
        stichtingsjaar = jaar;

    }
    /**
     *De locatie waar de ploeg speelt
     *
     *@param geef de locatie in waar de ploeg speelt
     */
    public void plaats(String locatie) {
        plaats = locatie;
    }

    public int getAantalGewonnenWedstrijden (int jaar) {
        for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijden) 
        {
            if(wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar) {
                w = wedstrijd;
            }    
            if(w.getThuisploeg() == naam) {
                if (w.getthuisDoelpunten()> w.getuitDoelpunten()) {
                    aantalGewonnenWedstrijden++;
                }

            }

        }

       return aantalGewonnenWedstrijden;
    }

     public int getDoelpuntensaldo (int jaar) {
        for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijden) 
        {
            if(wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar) {
                w = wedstrijd;
            }    
            if(w.getThuisploeg() == naam) {
                this.doelpuntensaldo = doelpuntensaldo + w.getthuisDoelpunten();
            }
            else if(w.getUitploeg() == naam) {
                this.doelpuntensaldo = doelpuntensaldo + w.getthuisDoelpunten();
            }

        }

       return doelpuntensaldo;
    }



    /**
     * Geef de naam van de ploeg
     * 
     * @return naam de naam van de ploeg
     */
    public String naam() {
        return naam;
    }
    /**
     * Geef het stichtingsjaar van de voetbalploeg
     * 
     * @return stichtingsjaar het stichtingsjaar van de ploeg
     */
    public int stichtingsjaar() {
        return stichtingsjaar;
    }
    /**
     * Geef de plaats waar de ploeg speelt
     * 
     * @return plaats de plaats van de ploeg
     * 
     */
    public String plaats() {
        return plaats;
    }
}
```

It gets stuck here:

```
if(wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar)
```

And my code for wedstrijd is:

```
/**
 * In deze klasse worden alle verschillende gegevens van de wedstrijden weergegeven.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Wedstrijd
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String thuisploeg;
    private String uitploeg;
    private double thuisscore;
    private double uitscore;
    private int thuisDoelpunten;
    private int uitDoelpunten;
    private String wedstrijdbespreking;
    private int jaar;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Wedstrijd
     */
    public Wedstrijd(int jaar)
    {
    thuisscore = 0;
    uitscore = 0;
    thuisDoelpunten = 0;
    uitDoelpunten = 0;
    this.jaar = jaar;

    }
    /**
     * Geef de thuisploeg in en het aantal doelpunten voor deze ploeg en de score voor de prestatie
     * van die bepaalde ploeg.
     * 
     * @param thuis thuis is de thuisploeg
     * @param thuisdoelpunten thuisdoelpunten zijn het aantal doelpunten voor de thuisploeg
     * @para, thuisscore geef de prestatie van de thuisploeg in
     */
    public void thuisploeg(String thuis,int thuisdoelpunten, double thuisscore) {
        thuisploeg = thuis;
        this.thuisDoelpunten = thuisdoelpunten;
        this.thuisscore = thuisscore;
        if(thuisscore > 10) {thuisscore = 10;}
    }

      /**
     * Geef de uitploeg in en het aantal doelpunten voor deze ploeg en de score voor de prestatie
     * van die ploeg
     * 
     * @param uit uit is de thuisploeg
     * @param uitdoelpunten thuisdoelpunten zijn het aantal doelpunten voor de uitploeg
     * @param uitscore geef de prestatie van de uitploeg in
     */

    public void uitploeg(String uit,int uitdoelpunten, int uitscore) {
        uitploeg = uit;
        this.uitDoelpunten = uitdoelpunten;
        this.uitscore = uitscore;
        if(uitscore > 10) {uitscore = 10;}

    }
    /**
     * Geef de wedstrijdstatistieken van de thuisploeg
     * 
     * @return thuisploeg geeft de statistieken van de thuisploeg
     */
    public String getThuisploeg() {
        return thuisploeg;
    }
    /**
     * Geef de wedstrijdstatistieken van de uitploeg
     * 
     * @return uitploeg geeft de statistieken van de uitploeg
     */

    public String getUitploeg() {
        return uitploeg;
    }

    public int getthuisDoelpunten() {
        return thuisDoelpunten;
    }

      public int getuitDoelpunten() {
        return uitDoelpunten;
    }

    public int getJaar() {
        return jaar;

    }
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you had the actual line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the NPE is thrown, and then to find out which value is null.

Comment: As `getDoelpuntensaldo()` calls `Wedstrijd`'s methods, the null pointer exception could very well be from there. can you post the code for `Wedstrijd` ?

Comment: As I say in my answer below, I don't see anywhere that the instance variable `wedstrijd` is initialized to a new instance of `Wedstrijd`.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard without a line number but my guess:

You have a variable

```
private Wedstrijd wedstrijd;
```

and then later you check

```
    if(wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar) {
        w = wedstrijd;
    }
```

If `wedstrijd` never got initialized or assigned anything, it will be null, and `wedstrijd.getJaar()` will throw a null pointer exception.

Edited to add: it looks like the line where the error is occurring is indeed what I suggest above.  The fix is probably to change

```
private Wedstrijd wedstrijd;
```

to

```
private Wedstrijd wedstrijd = new Wedstrijd();
```

But it's unclear what this local variable is for; currently it doesn't appear to be assigned anywhere, so the check for equality (`wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar) can't ever return true.

Comment: When i change it it says cannot find symbol - constructor Wedstrijd()

Comment: That was just an example; in the real Wedstrijd object the constructor requires `jaar`.  The larger point is: you have to initialize that object somewhere!